# The program clicks on the button that you need. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

He writes a program in Python with Selenium. On the website I have a button:

```
<button class="_rfh _4jy0 _4jy4 _517h _51sy _42ft" type="submit" value="1"><i alt="" class="_3-8_ img sp_DV9drRVqFBy sx_08f171"></i>Udostępnij</button>
```

and I write in my program that he would press this button:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_4jy0 _4jy4 _517h _51sy _42ft"]').click()
```

but the program does not click on this button but just clicks on another on this page that looks like this:

```
<button class="likeButton _4jy0 _4jy4 _517h _51sy _42ft" data-testid="page_profile_like_button_test_id" type="submit" value="1"><i alt="" class="_3-8_ img sp_DV9drRVqFBy sx_e53c72"></i>Lubię to!</button>
```

does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if class is dynamic or not, Also, check if below xpath is working for you

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit' and @value='1']"))).click()
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), 'Udostępnij')]"))).click()
```

**Note:** Please add below imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: I getting NameError: Name "WebDriverWait" is not defined

Comment: add import to your code :  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

Comment: What was the issue?  please provide log

Comment: NameError: Name "WebDriverWait" is not defined

Comment: is it resolved ? if not please provide code snippet which you are trying and wil verify from my end, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It won't paste all the code because it's too long. The place where the error occurs is:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), 'Udostępnij')]"))).click()
    if jakile == "nieskonczonosc":
        time.sleep(0.1)
    if jakile == "okreslonailosc":
        global i
        i += 1
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='mat-focus-indicator mat-icon-button mat-button-base mat-primary']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    time.sleep(2)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), 'Udostępnij')]"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    time.sleep(2)
    if jakile == "nieskonczonosc":
        time.sleep(0.1)
    if jakile == "okreslonailosc":
        if i > ileraz:
            driver.quit()
            skonczono()
    try:
        testt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/lp-root/lp-ui-wrapper/lp-main-ui/div[2]/lp-page-content/div/main/ng-component/ng-component/lp-available-actions-page/lp-card/lp-available-actions-list/lp-card/lp-overlay-wrapper/lp-card/div/lp-overlay-wrapper/lp-card/lp-card/div/mat-card/div[2]/span')
    except Exception:
        odpowiadanie_obserwowaniestronfb_2()
    driver.quit()
    zleskonczono()
```

Comment: please provide entire code snippet so that I can replicate this issue from my end. NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined is occured when import :: from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait is missing from your code.